# "Use these five questions to ask your supervisor to make sure you end up with what you will be treated."

Tags: grammar

“Use these five questions to ask your supervisor to make sure you end up with what you will be treated.”

This is a sentence in my advanced English textbook. I am having difficulty understanding the part ...'to make sure you end up with what you will be treated'.

To my mind, 'what you will be treated' is too definite, whereas 'make sure you end up with' indicates that it you may have an idea of what you will get, but it is far from definite.

Substituting 'will' for 'should' seems to make the sentence more comprehensible (at least to me).

The sentence is used to help explain the use of infinitives in a sentence, and also '..what..' grammatically.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Could someone explain why / why not?

Many thanks.

EDIT: changed '..with what..' to '..with..', as I realised with is part of 'end up with'.

Comment: It looks odd. It may help to quote the full sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is the full sentence and unfortunately there is no further context. The sentence is used as an example to help explain "with what..." grammatically.

Comment: My mistake. You’ve quoted the full sentence in the title, just not in the body of the question.

Comment: I'll add it to the body to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I don't know if it is grammatically incorrect, but it is possible for something to be both grammatically correct and nonsensical, and the end of that sentence doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The sentence doesn’t really make sense unless “treated” refers to a gift. What is that section of the textbook about? Perhaps the sentence contains a deliberate error that the surrounding text discusses.

Comment: The textbook contains a list of 3 sentences unrelated to each other to give examples of grammatical structures. It only instructs "Guess the grammatical function" while highlighting  the following - ask; to (make sure); what. It does not state what the grammatical functions are, or provide solutions.

Comment: @nnnnnn Keeping the same structure, and keeping 'will' I still can't make the sentence to make sense, for e.g., '...to make sure you end up with what you will receive'; '....to make sure you end up with what you will be given'....so I'm guessing there must be a rule there somewhere.

Comment: @BellyBoss The sentence is grammatical, but it's somewhat nonsensical. The specific use of *treated* aside, and discounting the exact syntax, it's the same on a conceptual level as the following: *Make sure that I do what I did.* It's playing with tenses in a way that sounds bizarre, because there's no need to make sure of anything that is preordained. (Unless, perhaps, it involves time travellers who go into the past and need to make sure that things unfold as they know they did before. In that context, it could make sense.)

Comment: I really can't tell what the original sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: The sentence would make more sense to me if "supervisor" were to be replaced with "doctor". Doctors treat people with drugs all the time, supervisors usually treat people in a different sense referring to the way they manage their subordinates. Even putting it into a medical setting, however, doesn't get rid of the impression I get that the person writing the book has reworked this sentence from one or more that made sense then didn't submit the text to the pulisher's editors before it was typeset.